# Mongoose referencing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created two Schemas, User and Whisp (a whisp is like a tweet).

```
//User
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true }
});

UserModel = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema);

module.exports.User = UserModel;

//Whisp
var WhispSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : String,
    created_at : Date,
    created_by : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "UserSchema"}//i want to ref User
});

var WhispModel = mongoose.model("WhispSchema", WhispSchema);

module.exports.Whisp = WhispModel;
```

Now in a route with express I want to create a new whisp.

```
var whisp = new Model.Whisp();
whisp.text = req.body.text;
Model.User.findOne({username: req.body.username }, function(err, userfound) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (userfound) {
        console.log(userfound._id);
        whisp.created_by = userfound._id;
    } else {
        res.send("Wrong Username");
    }
})
whisp.save(function(err, whispsaved) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Model.Whisp.findOne({_id: whispsaved._id })
        .populate('created_by')
        .exec(function(err, whispop) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log('The creator is %s', whispop.created_by.username);
        });
});
```

But I dont't know why whispop is always `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with references and everything to do with node's asynchronous nature.

The save function has to be in the callback of the Model.User.findOne function. Something like this:

```
var whisp = new Model.Whisp();
whisp.text = req.body.text;
Model.User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function (err, userfound) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (userfound) {
        console.log(userfound._id);
        whisp.created_by = userfound._id;
        whisp.save(function (err, whispsaved) {
            if (err) throw err;
            Model.Whisp
                    .findOne({_id: whispsaved._id})
                    .populate('created_by')
                    .exec(function (err, whispop) {
                        if (err) return handleError(err);
                        console.log('The creator is %s', whispop.created_by.username);
                    });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send("Wrong Username");
    }
});
```

Otherwise the save callback is executed before the findOne completes.

Comment: Thx man ! This work perfectly but I still don't understand why the  save function has to be in the callback of the Model.User.findOne function ^^.

Comment: @JohnyBro `Model.User.findOne` is an [asynchronous function](http://google.com/search?q=nodejs+what+is+asynchronous+function) which roughly speaking, means that anything inside its callback function  is executed much later. `whisp.save` however, since it was outside of that async callback, was executed immediately, ***before*** `whisp.created_by = userfound._id` had the chance to be executed. It seems un-intuitive but because of its async nature, the code that you wrote originally, wasn't exactly executed in that order (i.e. line-by-line). This answer correctly executes the code in that order.

Comment: Thx, I never see a response explicit like that now i understand that clearly, thx mate.